# Should DOM elements be defined to a variable?

Tags: javascript

For example in this object function I put the elements in a variable called Text array.  I then access the variable as needed.  However I could have just accessed the form directly as needed with out the variable.  Which way is best practice?  Also I could have used documentGetElementbyId as a third way.  I've also seen access to the DOM using just dot notaion with out the [].  That is 4 all together.  What is the best way to do it?  If it is case specefic..then what is the best way to do it for the object function below.

```
var Text = function( form_name ) 
{
    this.text_array = document.forms[form_name].elements;
};

Text.prototype.patterns = 
{
    prefix_url:     /^http:\/\//,
    url:            /^.{1,2048}$/,
    tweet:          /^.{1,40}$/, 
    title:          /^.{1,32}$/, 
    name:           /^.{1,64}$/, 
    email:          /^.{1,64}@.{1,255}$/,
    pass:           /^.{6,20}$/
};

Text.prototype.checkPattern = function( type ) 
{
    return this.patterns[type].exec( this.text_array[type].value );
};

Text.prototype.checkUrlAdd = function( type ) 
{
    return this.patterns[type].exec( this.text_array.url.value );
};  

Text.prototype.checkSameEmail = function() 
{
    return ( (this.text_array.email.value) === (this.text_array.email1.value) );
};

Text.prototype.checkEmpty = function() 
{
    var element;
    for ( element in this.text_array )
    {
        if( this.text_array[element].value === '' ) 
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
};
```

Comment: You don't need to cache `document.forms[form_name].elements`. The browser maintains those references, so it doesn't need to query the DOM when you access them.

Comment: Someone previously brought up the issue of resolving names i.e. name1.name2.name3....and decreasing the look up chain...is this valid?  Is this just for aesthetics..or performance...what do you suggest in this example...should I remove the variable and access directly?

Comment: @stackuser0 Well, `document` is a global variable. Identifier resolution takes longer for global variables, but we may be talking microseconds here. I wouldn't worry about that. However, the think is that you don't want repetition in your code. If you need to access `document.forms[form_name].elements` multiple times, you want to store it in a variable to avoid repetition.

Comment: There is also separation from the DOM and the library to consider...I've heard PHP developers sugget to separate the use of global variables from your code...i.e __SERVER, __POST, etc.  so I could say that the method above...reduces the lookup chain (possibly negligibly) and separates the DOM from the library a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of performance, we are not looking at much difference at all - if any.  In JavaScript, `document` is a global variable just like any other.  Therefore getting an element through `document.getElementById("someID")` does not take much more time then having previously saved that variable into another at some point or another and using that one.

Ex :

```
if(document.getElementById("myID").value == something) {
    /* do something here ... */
}
```

Will not be much faster/longer then

```
var myElem = document.getElementById("myId").value
if(myElem == something) {
    /* do something here ... */
}
```

The important thing to keep in mind is the readability and usability of your code.  Always think of it that if you hand this code off to someone else, will he be able to follow it.  Unless you are doing something for yourself and it is planned to be short lived, you will have to maintain/upgrade what you've done.  Sometimes it might take a few extra minutes writing the code, but if it'll save you hours down the road on maintenance, it's definetly worth it.

Hope this helps!

*Disclaimer :*
When I say not faster/slower then another execution is in terms of noticably.  There might (not 100% sure here) be a difference in microseconds... I see this as being negligable.

Comment: I think best practice is to save to a local variable..this reduces dependencies on global variables...+ uS faster!